# WordPress Quick Question . How to Get Parent Link in Submenu in My Code

Tags: php, functions, menus, sub-menu

I'm creating a menu walker from foundation 6 but problem is parent link is not click able, so solution might be that if we can get parent link in submenu but have some problem because I'm don't know much in PHP

```
class myfun_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {


    /**
     * Specify the item type to allow different walkers
     * @var array
     */
    var $nav_bar = '';
    function __construct( $nav_args = '' ) {
        $defaults = array(
            'item_type' => 'li',
            'in_top_bar' => false,
            'add_dividers' => false,
            'menu_type' => 'main-menu' //enable menu differenciation, used in preg_replace classes[] below
        );
        $this->nav_bar = apply_filters( 'req_nav_args', wp_parse_args( $nav_args, $defaults ) );
    }
    function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output ) {
        $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];
        if ( is_object( $args[0] ) ) {
            $args[0]->has_children = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );
        }
        return parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
    }
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
        $class_names = $value = '';
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;
        // Additionnal Class cleanup, as found in Roots_Nav_Walker - Roots Theme lib/nav.php
        // see http://roots.io/ and https://github.com/roots/roots
        $slug = sanitize_title($item->title);
        $classes = preg_replace('/(current(-menu-|[-_]page[-_])(item|parent|ancestor))/', '', $classes);
        $classes = preg_replace('/^((menu|page)[-_\w+]+)+/', '', $classes);
        $menu_type = $this->nav_bar['menu_type'];
        $classes[] = 'menu-item menu-item-' . $menu_type . ' menu-item-' . $slug;
        $classes = array_unique($classes);
        // Check for flyout
        $flyout_toggle = '';
        if ( $args->has_children && $this->nav_bar['item_type'] == 'li' ) {
            if ( $depth == 0 && $this->nav_bar['in_top_bar'] == false ) {
                $classes[] = 'has-flyout';
                $flyout_toggle = '<a href="#" class="flyout-toggle"><span></span></a>';
            } else if ( $this->nav_bar['in_top_bar'] == true ) {
                $classes[] = 'has-dropdown';
                $flyout_toggle = '';
            }
        }
        // Add 'active' class
        if ( $item->current == 1 || $item->current_item_ancestor == true ) {
            $classes[] = 'active';
        }
        if ( $is_button = in_array( 'call-to-action', $classes ) ) {
            // Replace the parent class with 'has-form'
            $classes[array_search( 'call-to-action', $classes )] = 'has-form';
        }
        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';
        if ( $depth > 0 ) {
            $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';
        } else {
            $output .= $indent . ( $this->nav_bar['in_top_bar'] && $this->nav_bar['add_dividers'] ? '<li class="divider"></li>' : '' ) . '<' . $this->nav_bar['item_type'] . ' id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';
        }
        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= $is_button                   ? ' class="button"' : '';
        $item_output  = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a '. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $flyout_toggle; // Add possible flyout toggle
        $item_output .= $args->after;
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
    function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        if ( $depth > 0 ) {
            $output .= "</li>\n";
        } else {
            $output .= "</" . $this->nav_bar['item_type'] . ">\n";
        }
    }
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {

        if ( $depth == 0 && $this->nav_bar['item_type'] == 'li' ) {
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", 1);
            $output .= $this->nav_bar['in_top_bar'] == true ? "\n$indent<ul class=\"vertical menu l1\">\n" : "\n$indent<ul class=\"flyout\">\n";
            $output .=  "NEEDED CODE HERE"; 
        } else {
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
            $output .= $this->nav_bar['in_top_bar'] == true ? "\n$indent<ul class=\"vertical menu l2\">\n" : "\n$indent<ul class=\"level-$depth\">\n";
        }
    }
}
```

I want parent link on last link at end on code where is write NEEDED CODE HERE
thank you